# Space out integer values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-order-by

I have a table with a unique int field that currently holds (mostly) consecutive values in a PostgreSQL database.

I would like to update these values keeping the same order, starting with the minimum value, but making sure that these values are spaced with some integer difference.

Example with spacing of 100:

```
before | after
-------|-------
   516 |   516
   520 |   616
  1020 |   716
  1021 |   816
  1022 |   916
  1816 |  1016
```

I tried solving this with sequences, but couldn't find a simple way to keep the order since `UPDATE` cannot use `ORDER BY`.

This is one-time 'housekeeping' task for a couple of hundred entries, so efficiency is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `PL` or `DO` (if you don't realy have to do it again). Here is a demo of how you can do it with `DO`

```
-- Temporal table for the demo:
CREATE TEMP TABLE demo (id integer,somecolumn integer);
INSERT INTO demo VALUES
(12,6766),
(22,9003),
(33,8656),
(50,6995),
(69,9151),
(96,9160);
-- DO function, here is where you make the ID change.
DO $$
DECLARE
    new_id integer := NULL;
    row integer := 0;
    rows_count integer := 0;
BEGIN
-- Create a temp table to change the id that will be droped at the end.
-- This table should have the same colums as the original table.
    CREATE TEMP TABLE demo_temp (id integer,somecolumn integer) ON COMMIT DROP;
-- Get the initial id
    new_id := id FROM demo ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
-- Get the rows count for the loop
    rows_count := COUNT(*) FROM demo;
    LOOP
-- Insert into temp table adding the new id.
-- This loops for every row to make sure you have the same order and data.
        INSERT into demo_temp(id,somecolumn)
        SELECT new_id,somecolumn FROM demo ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 OFFSET row;
-- Adding 100 to id
        new_id := new_id+100;
-- Loop control
        row := row+1;
        EXIT WHEN rows_count = row;
    END LOOP;
-- Clean original table
    TRUNCATE demo;
-- Insert temp table with new id
    INSERT INTO demo(id,somecolumn) SELECT id,somecolumn FROM demo_temp;
END $$;
-- See result:
SELECT * FROM demo;
```

This last select resturns the New Table:

```
New Table:                  Old Table:
id  |  somecolumn           id  |  somecolumn
----+-------------          ----+-------------
12  |  6766                 12  |  6766
112 |  9003                 22  |  9003
212 |  8656                 33  |  8656
312 |  6995                 50  |  6995
412 |  9151                 69  |  9151
512 |  9160                 96  |  9160
```

Comment: **NOTE:** If the original table has a sequence you could add the update of the sequence after the `DO` or at the end of the `DO`